# Как открыть окно чата в telegram?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, telegram

Есть приложение написанное на xamarin. 
В приложении есть список контактов. Необходим функционал который сможет открывать окно чата-телеграмм с контактом по номеру телефона, который указан в профиле контакта. Как это возможно сделать? Нашел что можно tg://resolve?domain=username, но у пользователя может и не быть username, да и приложение его не знает.

Подскажите какие-либо примеры или хотя бы где смотреть?
На сайте самого телеграмма вообще ничего похоже не нашел, кроме создания ботов и веб-запросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, не нашел решение, как это можно сделать для платформы Android. Решение для iOS было просто "tg://msg=&to=<номер телефона>"
Android:
Нашел что контакты telegram хрант с специальным типом и необходимо найти этот контакт с номером и спец типом, а потом из DATA2 вытащить userid пользователя. Зная userId пользователя телеграм уже можно открыть чат с ним. Есть проблема в том что контакт с данными должен быть уже сохранен в адресной книге.

Answer (score 0):

Тем кто будет искать ответ :

```
PhoneNstr="79876543210";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tg:resolve?phone="+PhoneNstr));
intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]